# Sharepoint Online 2013 Menu Snippet

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, managed-navigation

I am using Design Manager to add the menu snippet in my page layout in SharePoint Online 2013. How do I go about adding a drop down menu. I wanted to add managed navigation but there is no Navigation menu in site settings.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable publishing feature.

**Enable publishing at the site level**

- On the Site Settings page, in the Site Administration section, click Site features.
- Next to Office SharePoint Server Publishing, click Activate.

**Enable publishing at the site collection level**

- If you are not at the root of your site, under Site Collection Administration, click Go to top level site settings.
- On the Site Settings page, under Site Collection Administration, click Site collection features.
- On the Site Collection Features page, next to Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure, click Activate.

Comment: These options are not available for the public facing site collection

Comment: Oh for public facing site the feature enabling is not possible. So navigation as well as managed navigation is out of question.